# Запись из unput c разделителем "," в Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

Всем привет!
Не могу понять как записать данные разделённые "," из input в mysql.

Я понимаю как записывать одно значение в одну строку, но не могу понять как записать данные через запятую в разные строки(ячейки).

```
$data = explode(', ', $_POST['all_add'] );

foreach ($data as $value) {
     $query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `emails` (`UserEmails`) VALUES ('$value')");
     {
     echo "Успешно добавил!";
     }
}
```

Так же пробую так. Он делит значения из input и обрабатывает каждое, которое написано через запятую. Но  значения не попадают в базу. Куда нужно передать $value в этом запросе?

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
     $query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `emails` (`UserEmails`)
     SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@csv_value, ',', nums.num), ',', -1)
     FROM ( SELECT 1 num UNION SELECT 2 UNION ... UNION SELECT NNN ) nums");
     {
     echo "Успешно добавил!";
     }
}
```

Проблема решена!
Что бы положить данные в таблицу, нужно $value помесить в ещё один запрос на добавление в таблицу.

```
$add = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `emails` (`UserEmails`) VALUES ('$value')");
```

Спасибо всем кто помог.

Версия MySQL - 5.7

Comment: В чём смысл делать таблицу `emails`? Проектирование хромает, мягко говоря

Comment: _Как добавлять разные значение разделённые "," в разные строки._ Это как понимать?.. Вы в UserEmails вставляете данные $_POST['new_email'] - что не так?

Comment: @InDevX
Я хочу сделать так что бы в  input помещались данные с разделителем к примеру: max, petya, vasya
И потом их отдельно записывать в бд

Comment: `$data = explode(',', $_POST['new_email'] );` - получится массив, можно циклом пройтись и записать

Comment: @InDevX
Я поправил код, но записывает пустое значение в одну ячейку, а не в разные.

Comment: Т.е. надо передать на MySQL одно значение с CSV-списком, там поделить его на отдельные значения и сохранить в несколько записей, одно значение на запись? Ну тут решение очень зависит от точной версии MySQL.

Comment: @Akina Моя версия 5.7. Можешь подробнее рассказать? Как запись из ипута, сделать списком со значениями которое разделы запятой. И как правильно писать цикл?  
Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Следующий вопрос - каково максимальное количество отдельных значений в передаваемом CSV?

Comment: @Akina Я хочу передавать 100-500 значений. Я про это много читал, и не один способ не помог, всего чего я смог добиться описал в вопросе. Он просто записывает пустое значение. Сам ипут с ```name="all_add[]"```

Comment: если у тебя name="all_add[]", то с чего ты решил что у тебя там есть хоть одна запятая?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO table (column)
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@csv_value, ',', nums.num), ',', -1)
FROM ( SELECT 1 num UNION SELECT 2 UNION ... UNION SELECT NNN ) nums
-- WHERE nums.num <= 1 + LENGTH(@csv_value) - LENGTH(REPLACE(@csv_value, ',', ''))
```

Подзапрос генерации `num` для 500 значений разумнее создать как JOIN трёх подзапросов по 8 чисел от 0 до 7.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123518/discussion-on-answer-by-akina---unput-c---mysql).